# C# NUnit TestCaseSource Passing Parameter

Tags: c#, nunit

I have the following method which generates a set of test cases!

```
public IEnumerable<ResultsOfCallMyMethod> PrepareTestCases(param1)
{
    foreach (string entry in entries)
    {
        yield return callMyMethod(param1);
    }
}
```

How can I pass param which is of type string as a parameter to my `PrepareTestCases()` method?

Is there a way to do the following:

```
[Test, Category("Integration"), TestCaseSource("PrepareTestCases", param1)]
public void TestRun(ResultsOfCallMyMethod testData)
{
    // do something!
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869734/how-to-use-testcase-in-nunit-2-5

Comment: That is not what I was looking for!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at [TestCaseSourceAttribute doc](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.4) you will see there is no any way to pass the parameter to the method which returns test cases.

The method, which generates test cases, should be **parameterless**.

So, assuming you are going to avoid code duplication and you need to reuse the same method to generate a few test case lists, I'd recommend you to do the following:

1. Write parameterized method which actually generates test cases sets:
   (`PrepareTestCases()` already does that)

   ```
   public IEnumerable<ResultsOfCallMyMethod> PrepareTestCases(string param)
   {
       foreach (string entry in entries)
       {
           yield return CallMyMethod(param);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Write parameterless wrappers which call test cases generator and pass desired parameter there:

   ```
   public IEnumerable<ResultsOfCallMyMethod> PrepareTestCases_Param1()
   {
       return PrepareTestCases("param1");
   }

   public IEnumerable<ResultsOfCallMyMethod> PrepareTestCases_Param2()
   {
       return PrepareTestCases("param2");
   }
   ```
3. Write test methods and pass paremeterless wrappers there as test case sources:

   ```
   [TestCaseSource("PrepareTestCases_Param1")]
   public void TestRun1(ResultsOfCallMyMethod data)
   {
   }

   [TestCaseSource("PrepareTestCases_Param2")]
   public void TestRun2(ResultsOfCallMyMethod data)
   {
   }
   ```

Comment: I think the `PrepareTestCases_Param1` etc. need to be static: "The sourceName specified on a TestCaseSourceAttribute must refer to a static field, property or method."

Answer (score 26):

I've made a change for this in the latest version of nunit which is about to be released (3.2).

https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/4f54fd7e86f659682e7a538dfe5abee0c33aa8b4/CHANGES.txt

> - TestCaseSourceAttribute now optionally takes an array of parameters
>     that can be passed to the source method

It is now possible to do something like this

```
[Test, Category("Integration"), TestCaseSource(typeof(MyDataSources),"PrepareTestCases", new object[] {param1})]
public void TestRun(ResultsOfCallMyMethod testData)
{
// do something!
}

private class MyDataSources
{
  public IEnumerable<ResultsOfCallMyMethod> PrepareTestCases(param1)
  {
    foreach (string entry in entries)
    {
        yield return callMyMethod(param1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I got a compile error for this: Error CS0182: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type. What am I missing?

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out: object[] must be explicitly written. Btw nameof() also allowed despite of the error message

Answer (score 1):

In my case I would like to load data from a CSV file but I couldn't pass the filename to the "datasource".
After struggling a bit around I come to this two cent solution.

At first I inherited TestCaseSourceAttirbute

```
/// <summary>
/// FactoryAttribute indicates the source to be used to provide test cases for a test method.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class TestCaseCsvAttribute : TestCaseSourceAttribute 
{
    public TestCaseCsvAttribute(Type mapped, Type config) : base(typeof(TestCsvReader<,>).MakeGenericType(mapped, config), "Data")
    { }
}
```

then I created the data layer, in my case a CSV reader.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Test data provider
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type to return in enumerable</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="C">Configuration type that provide Filenames</typeparam>
    public sealed class TestCsvReader<T, C>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TestCsvReader{T, C}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public TestCsvReader()
        {
            this.Config = (C)Activator.CreateInstance<C>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the configuration.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The configuration.
        /// </value>
        private C Config { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the filename.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The filename.
        /// </value>
        /// <exception cref="System.Exception">
        /// </exception>
        private string Filename
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    string result = Convert.ToString(typeof(C).GetProperty(string.Format("{0}Filename", typeof(T).Name)).GetValue(this.Config));
                    if (!File.Exists(result))
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to find file '{0}' specified in property '{1}Filename' in class '{1}'", result, typeof(C).Name));

                    return result;
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to find property '{0}Filename' in class '{1}'", typeof(T).Name, typeof(C).Name));
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Yields values from source
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IEnumerable Data()
        {
            string file = this.Filename;

            T[] result = null;
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(file))
            {
                //TODO: do it here your magic
            }
            yield return new TestCaseData(result);
        }
}
```

Then I created a class with the only scope to contain properties with the file paths. There's a name convention about the property, that's ClassTypeName + "Filename".

```
public class Configurations
{
    public string ConflictDataFilename
    {
        get
        {
            return @"C:\test.csv";
        }
    }
}
```

At this point just decorate accordingly the test, with the type of class to map to data and the class that contain file path.

```
[Test(Description="Try this one")]
[TestCaseCsv(typeof(ClassMappedToData), typeof(Configurations))]
public void Infinite(ClassMappedToData[] data)
{
}
```

Hope this can help a bit.